# How to turn a method to a callback procedure in 64bit Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, assembly

The MustangPeak Common Library (http://code.google.com/p/mustangpeakcommonlib/) contains the following code that converts a method to a procedure that can be used in a callback:

```
const
  AsmPopEDX = $5A;
  AsmMovEAX = $B8;
  AsmPushEAX = $50;
  AsmPushEDX = $52;
  AsmJmpShort = $E9;

type
  TStub = packed record
    PopEDX: Byte;
    MovEAX: Byte;
    SelfPointer: Pointer;
    PushEAX: Byte;
    PushEDX: Byte;
    JmpShort: Byte;
    Displacement: Integer;
  end;

{ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
function CreateStub(ObjectPtr: Pointer; MethodPtr: Pointer): Pointer;
var
  Stub: ^TStub;
begin
  // Allocate memory for the stub
  // 1/10/04 Support for 64 bit, executable code must be in virtual space
  Stub := VirtualAlloc(nil, SizeOf(TStub), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

  // Pop the return address off the stack
  Stub^.PopEDX := AsmPopEDX;

  // Push the object pointer on the stack
  Stub^.MovEAX := AsmMovEAX;
  Stub^.SelfPointer := ObjectPtr;
  Stub^.PushEAX := AsmPushEAX;

  // Push the return address back on the stack
  Stub^.PushEDX := AsmPushEDX;

  // Jump to the 'real' procedure, the method.
  Stub^.JmpShort := AsmJmpShort;
  Stub^.Displacement := (Integer(MethodPtr) - Integer(@(Stub^.JmpShort))) -
    (SizeOf(Stub^.JmpShort) + SizeOf(Stub^.Displacement));

  // Return a pointer to the stub
  Result := Stub;
end;
{ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- }

{ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
procedure DisposeStub(Stub: Pointer);
begin
  // 1/10/04 Support for 64 bit, executable code must be in virtual space
  VirtualFree(Stub, SizeOf(TStub),MEM_DECOMMIT);
end;
```

I would appreciate any help in converting it to 64bit.  I know that the calling convention in Win64 is different and that up to four parameters are passed into registers. So CreateStub may have to be modified to include the number of parameters.  It is actually not used with more than four parameters which are integers or pointers (no floating point arguments).

Comment: Comments indicate that it already supports 64 bit. Perhaps those comments are misleading! All the same, look at the VCL source for StdWndProc for a sample code doing something very similar.

Comment: The comment is misleading.  It is meant to say that if you allocate memory with GetMem instead of VirtualAlloc it would create a problem in 64bit processors (DEP protection).

Comment: When you use this in 32 bit code, do you need to make your method pointer `stdcall`?

Comment: It's going to be much harder in 64 bit. In fact I'm pretty sure such a simple approach won't readily work. For x86-64 there is in fact a single calling convention. It makes extensive use of registers. The trick that makes `CreateStub` work in 32 bit relies on `stdcall` pushing everything on the stack. In x86-64 you'd need to shift everything along and that's much harder with registers than with the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the 64-bit version of CreateStub.  Kudos to Andrey Gruzdev who provided the code.

```
  type
  ICallbackStub = interface(IInterface)
    function GetStubPointer: Pointer;
    property StubPointer : Pointer read GetStubPointer;
  end;

  TCallbackStub = class(TInterfacedObject, ICallbackStub)
  private
    fStubPointer : Pointer;
    fCodeSize : integer;
    function GetStubPointer: Pointer; 
  public
    constructor Create(Obj : TObject; MethodPtr: Pointer; NumArgs : integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;



constructor TCallBackStub.Create(Obj: TObject; MethodPtr: Pointer;
  NumArgs: integer);
{$IFNDEF CPUX64}
// as before
{$ELSE CPUX64}
const
RegParamCount = 4;
ShadowParamCount = 4;

Size32Bit = 4;
Size64Bit = 8;

ShadowStack   = ShadowParamCount * Size64Bit;
SkipParamCount = RegParamCount - ShadowParamCount;

StackSrsOffset = 3;
c64stack: array[0..14] of byte = (
$48, $81, $ec, 00, 00, 00, 00,//     sub rsp,$0
$4c, $89, $8c, $24, ShadowStack, 00, 00, 00//     mov [rsp+$20],r9
);

CopySrcOffset=4;
CopyDstOffset=4;
c64copy: array[0..15] of byte = (
$4c, $8b, $8c, $24,  00, 00, 00, 00,//     mov r9,[rsp+0]
$4c, $89, $8c, $24, 00, 00, 00, 00//     mov [rsp+0],r9
);

RegMethodOffset = 10;
RegSelfOffset = 11;
c64regs: array[0..28] of byte = (
$4d, $89, $c1,      //   mov r9,r8
$49, $89, $d0,      //   mov r8,rdx
$48, $89, $ca,      //   mov rdx,rcx
$48, $b9, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, // mov rcx, Obj
$48, $b8, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00 // mov rax, MethodPtr
);

c64jump: array[0..2] of byte = (
$48, $ff, $e0  // jump rax
);

CallOffset = 6;
c64call: array[0..10] of byte = (
$48, $ff, $d0,    //    call rax
$48, $81,$c4,  00, 00, 00, 00,   //     add rsp,$0
$c3// ret
);
var
  i: Integer;
  P,PP,Q: PByte;
  lCount : integer;
  lSize : integer;
  lOffset : integer;
begin
    lCount := SizeOf(c64regs);
    if NumArgs>=RegParamCount then
       Inc(lCount,sizeof(c64stack)+(NumArgs-RegParamCount)*sizeof(c64copy)+sizeof(c64call))
    else
       Inc(lCount,sizeof(c64jump));

    Q := VirtualAlloc(nil, lCount, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    P := Q;

    lSize := 0;
    if NumArgs>=RegParamCount then
    begin
        lSize := ( 1+ ((NumArgs + 1 - SkipParamCount) div 2) * 2 )* Size64Bit;   // 16 byte stack align

        pp := p;
        move(c64stack,P^,SizeOf(c64stack));
        Inc(P,StackSrsOffset);
        move(lSize,P^,Size32Bit);
        p := pp;
        Inc(P,SizeOf(c64stack));
        for I := 0 to NumArgs - RegParamCount -1 do
        begin
            pp := p;
            move(c64copy,P^,SizeOf(c64copy));
            Inc(P,CopySrcOffset);
            lOffset := lSize + (i+ShadowParamCount+1)*Size64Bit;
            move(lOffset,P^,Size32Bit);
            Inc(P,CopyDstOffset+Size32Bit);
            lOffset := (i+ShadowParamCount+1)*Size64Bit;
            move(lOffset,P^,Size32Bit);
            p := pp;
            Inc(P,SizeOf(c64copy));
        end;
    end;

    pp := p;
    move(c64regs,P^,SizeOf(c64regs));
    Inc(P,RegSelfOffset);
    move(Obj,P^,SizeOf(Obj));
    Inc(P,RegMethodOffset);
    move(MethodPtr,P^,SizeOf(MethodPtr));
    p := pp;
    Inc(P,SizeOf(c64regs));

    if NumArgs<RegParamCount then
      move(c64jump,P^,SizeOf(c64jump))
    else
    begin
      move(c64call,P^,SizeOf(c64call));
      Inc(P,CallOffset);
      move(lSize,P^,Size32Bit);
    end;
    fCodeSize := lcount;
   fStubPointer := Q;
{$ENDIF CPUX64}
end;

destructor TCallBackStub.Destroy;
begin
  VirtualFree(fStubPointer, fCodeSize, MEM_DECOMMIT);
  inherited;
end;

function TCallBackStub.GetStubPointer: Pointer;
begin
  Result := fStubPointer;
end;
```

Comment: PyScriper, You are a gentleman and a scholar. I have given you Commit access to the Mustangpeak code on Google to implement this. I just did not have enough skill or time to fix this. If you make VSTools compile 64Bit I will buy you a pint! I have moved mostly to Macs so my interest in VSTools is low these days but there are a lot of users who would love a 64 Bit version! Thanks,
Jim

Comment: For an example on how to use this see https://code.google.com/p/mustangpeakcommonlib/
; this link points to the source file: [link](https://code.google.com/p/mustangpeakcommonlib/source/browse/trunk/Source/MPCommonUtilities.pas)

Answer (score 3):

I'm 99% convinced that there is no equivalent solution on x64. On x86 the code takes advantage of the property of `stdcall` that all parameters are passed on the stack. The code that creates the *stub* does not need to know anything about the parameters that are passed. It simply pushes an extra parameter, the self pointer, onto the stack. All the other parameters are shifted down the stack.

On x64, at least on Windows, there is a [single calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention). This calling convention makes extensive use of registers. When the registers are exhausted, the stack is used. Both integer and floating point registers are used. The rules for which parameters get passed in which registers are complex to say the least. So, in order to convert a method into a free standing procedure, it is my belief that the `CreateStub` routine would need to know information about the parameters: how many parameters, what types etc. Since `CreateStub` has none of this information, it is simply not possible to make an x64 conversion of this function, with the same interface.

Comment: Is it not possible to have a CreateStub with an extra argument the number of parameters (say 0 to 4) under the assumption that they are either integer of pointers (i.e. they fit in the standard registers)?  I would assume that assembler code would just add Self to the appropriate register depending on the number of parameters of add it to the stack if we run out of registers.

Comment: Further to the previous comment, you have to shift the registers.  If say you have two parameters:  MOV R8, RDX then MOV RDX, RCX and finally push Self to to RCX.

Comment: For a small number of parameters you'll probably be able to get something working. One thing I have not studied is how the return value is handled. It would make sense to pass the parameter count to a 64 bit CreateStub.